# How do I configure Azure DNS to forward domain requests to a server with no public IP address?

Tags: domain-name-system, azure

I have a domain registered through and external provider, say `x.y.com`, and want requests to this domain to be passed to an Azure VM with no public IP.

I've created an Azure DNS resource named `x.y.com` in the same resource group as my VM and arranged for the admin of my domain to point the domain's name servers to the given Azure name servers.

Then I pointed the A record to the internal/private IP of my server - `10.0.0.4` - but when I ping the domain from an external computer I get `10.0.0.4`, which obviously is not visible from outside the Azure private network.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Hi Peter, I believe you may be misunderstanding how DNS works. A DNS record is simply a text representation of an ip address. Therefore if your VM is listening on a private ip address, nothing outside this VM's private network will be able to access it, regardless of it's DNS.

You probably need to configure a load balancer that will ferry your data from the public internet to your VM's private ip address. Another option would be providing your VM with a public ip address.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as you will see from my answer, Azure provides infrastructure which has sight of internal resources and allows traffic to be routed to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working the way I want it to as follows:

1. Make sure that your VM has a "Public IP Address" resource associated with it ("Public IP" is a misnomer, as you will see).

   - Give this "Public IP Address" resource a recognisable name, eg. `{VM-name}-dynamic-ip`
   - Set the Assignment type to "Dynamic".  When you do this, there is *no static public IP address* - instead Azure gives a domain name such as `xy.cloudapp.azure.com` which they will route to your VM.
   - Now we want also to route our external domain `x.y.com` to that VM - but that normally requires providing a static IP address, which we don't have.  Here's how to do it using Azure's internal infrastructure.
2. Setup an Azure DNS Zone for your domain `x.y.com` in the same Resource Group as the VM (or loadbalancer) you want to direct traffic to.
3. A list of 4 name servers will show in the top right of the DNS Zone Overview screen.  If your domain is managed/administered outside of Azure, you will need to get the nameservers it is linked to changed to match these Azure servers.  For example my first one is `ns1-02.azure-dns.com`.
4. Create/Edit the `A` record of your DNS Zone.  It should have a default name of `@.x.y.com`

   - Under "Alias Record set" choose "Yes"
   - Under "Alias type" choose "Azure resource"
   - Select your current subscription
   - Now under "Azure resource" you will be able to select your "public" IP address, `{VM-name}-dynamic-ip`
5. You'll probably want to setup a CNAME record for your resource too, just as you would normally.  I don't think this is required, though.

As I understand it this DNS Zone gets registered with the Azure Name Servers and is able to route traffic to resources which are otherwise private to your Azure virtual network.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you get the name resolution to work that way, there is no public endpoint for your traffic to enter your vNET and reach your server. If you can’t have a public IP on your server I would deploy a Azure Firewall that will NAT the traffic and point the DNS to the firewall public IP

https://www.petri.com/understanding-and-creating-nat-rules-in-azure-firewall

Comment: Thanks, but this still requires a static public IP address - it just moves it to the firewall.

Comment: @Peter You got me curious, why can’t you have a public IP when it solves your problems?

Comment: A public IP is expensive compared to dynamic networking, and while the overall cost is small it indicates that Microsoft is discouraging static IPs - understandable, since they are limited resource and tying one permanently to a resource means they have one less in their pool.  Dynamic routing internal to Azure allows them to allocate IPs how they like.

Comment: Ok! As far as I know you will need some kind of public endpoint in order for external traffic to reach your internal resources. I hope you find a solution that works!